# Oauth using HWIOAuthBundle for a specific TLD

Tags: symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I've a strange problem, we've got a symfony application that uses google/oauth through HWIOAuthBundle for login, that always works well for every user, our application is worldwide spread, so recently we've got a problem with an specific tld .eg, the rest of the world can authenticate except the egypt.

When someone from Egypt try authenticate, the application redirects to the page login again, I received to status redirect code before that:
302: Moved temporarily
302: Found.

I don't know if is enough information, on my point of view isn't a symfony appllication problem, because is working for the whole world except egypt, and only happens for .net.br in our homolog environment when application is on live using .com.br is working properly included for Egypt.